# How do you get the ending address of an array in memory? C programming

Tags: c, memory, memory-address

If I have an address in memory for the start of an integer array, how do I figure out the end address of the array?

For example, if an array started at 0xFF000000 how would you return the address where the array ends?

Comment: How many elements does the array have? How big "integer" is on your platform?

Comment: As given, you cannot.

Comment: What if you were able to find the size of the array from the address? I tried using `int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;` but that just print's out a bunch of jibberish.

Comment: You **can't** find the size of an array from *only* its address. What is the actual problem? Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I stated my problem? That's why I made this post. There has to be some sort of way to get the array size from it's address. The first address is [0] for the array so there is an ending.

Comment: No, there is not, as another commenter has stated. The length of the array is what your code defines it to be. An array in C is not an independant entity that contains all its properties.

Answer (score 0):

given an address for an array of integers, you need to know how many are in the array since an integer can be zero. in other words without a delimiter indicated the end of the array, there is no way to know how many values were ACTUALLY stored in the array.

a basic heap array should at least have a second variable storing the number of elements. how else was it allocated right?

`int nElements = 10;
    int *pInts = (int*)malloc(nElements * sizeof(int));
    int *pEndOfArrayAddress = pInts + (nElements-1);`

Comment: Pointer arithmetic knows the size of each element. It works in the same way as array indexing, so +1 goes to the second element irrespective of the type.

Comment: weather vane: sure. I'm being very explicit and clear for Joey. my bad

Comment: No, you are being misleading. You should not use `sizeof(<type>)` in pointer arithmectic.